# Integrating $xe^{x} \cos x$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Please help me to integrate the following function. I'm unsure of following a particular method .

$$xe^{x}\cos x $$

Comment: A double integration by parts?

Answer (score 4):

use integral by part and get
$$u=x$$ and $$ dv=e^{x}cosx$$
for finding v use integral by part again

Comment: @shere...Why wouldn't we use x=$xe^x\cos x $...?

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$
\int xe^x(\cos x+i\sin x)\,dx=\int xe^{(1+i)x}\,dx
$$
With the substitution $t=(1+i)x$, this becomes
$$
\frac{1}{(1+i)^2}\int te^t\,dt=\frac{1}{(1+i)^2}e^t(t-1)=
-\frac{1}{2}ie^x(\cos x+i\sin x)(x-1+ix)
$$
(the antiderivative of $te^t$ is an easy integration by parts). Now compute the real part: disregarding $\frac{1}{2}e^x$, we have
$$
(\sin x-i\cos x)(x-1+ix)=(x-1)\sin x+x\cos x+i(x\sin x-(x-1)\cos x)
$$
Final answer:
$$
\int xe^x\cos x=\frac{e^x}{2}(x\sin x+x\cos x-\sin x)+c
$$
and also
$$
\int xe^x\sin x=\frac{e^x}{2}(x\sin x-x\cos x+\cos x)+c
$$

Answer (score 2):

setting $$f=x$$ and $$dg=e^x\cos(x)dx$$ then we get
$$df=1$$ and $$g=\frac{1}{2}e^x(\sin(x)+\cos(x)$$ and we get
$$\frac{1}{2}e^xx\left(\sin(x)+\cos(x)\right)-\frac{1}{2}\int e^x\sin(x)dx-\frac{1}{2}\int e^x\cos(x)dx$$